# How do I prevent the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()."?

Tags: javascript

I am facing this problem in a chrome browser. When I click on any audio, it throws an exception. My audio tag is in a loop, and when I click on the audio or refresh it using ajax, then the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help you, but I still leave my comment so maybe it will help somebody else. 
I had similar issue, and the solution proposed by @dighan on bountysource.com/issues/ solved it for me.

So here is the code that solved my problem:

```
var media = document.getElementById("YourVideo");
const playPromise = media.play();
if (playPromise !== null){
    playPromise.catch(() => { media.play(); })
}
```

Just add it in document.ready

It still throws an error into console, but at least the video is playing :)
I think this should work for audio as well.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: @FelixSFD ok, won't do so again.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when my `media` wasn't loaded. Check these:

1. Your `media` has the correct `src`.
2. Your `media` is loaded before you play it.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently noticed this happening on one of my sites that had no problems before, and hasn't been changed at all. It appears to be a known bug in Chrome -- take a look at the issue tracker here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=593273

It seems that there is no way to prevent the error until this is fixed by the Chrome team.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12333840)

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Thanks for the advice. There does not currently appear to be a solution to the OP's question -- I've updated my answer to reflect that. I'm guessing your comment is a stock response, but how did I require clarification from the OP?

Comment: This does answer the OP's question, "you can't" is just not the answer anyone was hoping for.